# Which Java Regex can I use to match a URL that has a capital letter before the query string?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that matches a URL that has a capital letter before the query string.  I want to capture the query string including the question mark and I want to capture the non-query string part. If there is no query string, but there is a capital letter, then the non query string part should be captured.

A few examples:

```
/contextroot/page.html?param1=value1&param2=value2 NO MATCH
/contextroot/page.html?param=VALUE&param2=value2   NO MATCH

/contextroot/Page.html?param=value                 MATCH
/contextroot/Page.html                             GROUP 1
?param=value                                       GROUP 2

/contextroot/page.HTML                             MATCH
/contextroot/page.HTML                             GROUP 1
```

Here's my first cut at the regex:

```
^(.*[A-Z].*)(\??.*)$
```

It's busted.  This never captures the query string.

Comment: If you want a parser, write a parser.

Comment: In your examples, what do you call "the query string" you want to capture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^/contextroot/([^?]*[A-Z][^?]*)(\?.*)?$
```

Explanation:

```
^/contextroot/  # literal start of URL
(               # match group 1
  [^?]*         # anything except `?` (zero or more)
  [A-Z]         # one capital letter
  [^?]*         # see above
)
(               # match group 2
  \?            # one ?
  .*            # anything that follows
)?              # optionally
$               # end of string
```

Comment: The first `[^?]*` should probably be `[^?]*?` or `[^?A-Z]*` to avoid some backtracking, but otherwise +1 for not using look-aheads.

Answer (score 2):

```
(^/contextroot/(?=[^?A-Z]*[A-Z])[^?]*)(\?.*)?
```

Explanation:

```
(                 # match group 1
  ^/contextroot/  #   literal start of URL (optional, remove if not needed)
  (?=             #   positive look-ahead...
    [^?A-Z]*      #     anything but a question mark or upper-case letters
    [A-Z]         #     a mandatory upper-case letter
  )               #   end look-ahead
  [^?]*           #   match anything but a question mark
)                 # end group 1
(                 # match group 2
  \?.*            #   a question mark and the rest of the query string
)?                # end group 2, make optional
```

Note that this is intended to check a single URL and does not work when run against a multi-line string.

To make it work with multi-line input (one URL per line), make this change:

```
(^/contextroot/(?=[^?A-Z\r\n]*[A-Z])[^?\r\n]*)(\?.*)?
```

Comment: Fails on `/contextroot/Page.html?param=value`, unless you change the `+` to a `*`.

Comment: Right! Wow, stupid error. Thanks @Tim, that and another error is fixed now.